# RegExp logical problem with variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, variables

we have some checkboxes and When each of the checkes comes true, a value will be added to a **single textbox**.

and when each of the checkes comes false,
**their own value** will be deleted.

I hope I explained well.

any way...
here is my code:

```
<script>
      function <?php echo $fff; ?>q(){
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $chid;  ?>').checked = false;
            var v;
            v=document.getElementById('<?php echo $lblid; ?>').innerText;
            var ab;
            ab=document.getElementById('ab').value;
            var t;
            let a = document.getElementById('<?php echo $idlevel; ?>').innerText;
            const b = document.getElementById('<?php echo $txtid; ?>').value;
            const c = '-' + b + '-' + a;
            var reg;
            reg= new RegExp(c, 'g');
            t=ab.replace(reg,'');
            document.getElementById('ab').value=t;
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $lblid; ?>').innerHTML='<?php echo $talent; ?>';
        }
</script>
```

I do know that it is not a clean code:)

btw `ab` is my textbox.
and `c` is my value.

but problem is :
`reg= new RegExp(c, 'g');` part doesn't
accept `c` as value.

it works when I do this:`reg= new RegExp('word', 'g');`

but it doesn't accept any variable.

pls help.

Comment: If you know the code isn't clean, it would've been worth cleaning it before asking. Also better variables names would make things easier too. Could you define "it doesn't accept any variable." what actually happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
 const c = '-' + b + '-' + a;
 var newString = new String(c)
 var reg = new RegExp(newString, "g");
```